# Import broker definitions into Dockerized RabbitMQ

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

I have a RabbitMQ broker with some exchanges and queues already defined. I know I can export and import these definitions via the HTTP API. I want to Dockerize it, and have all the broker definitions imported when it starts.

Ideally, it would be done as easily as it is done via the API. I could write a bunch of `rabbitmqctl` commands, but with a lot of definitions this might take quite a some time. Also, every change somebody else makes through the web interface will have to be inserted.

I have managed to do what I want by writing a script that sleeps a curl request and starts the server, but this seems to be error prone and really not elegant. Are there any better ways to do definition importing/exporting
, or is this the best that can be done?

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM rabbitmq:management
LABEL description="Rabbit image" version="0.0.1"
ADD init.sh /init.sh          
ADD rabbit_e6f2965776b0_2015-7-14.json /rabbit_config.json         
CMD ["/init.sh"]
```

init.sh

```
sleep 10 && curl -i -u guest:guest -d @/rabbit_config.json -H "content-type:application/json" http://localhost:15672/api/definitions -X POST &

rabbitmq-server $@
```

Answer (score 11):

1. Export definitions using `rabbitmqadmin export rabbit.definitions.json`.
2. Add them inside the image using your Dockerfile: `ADD rabbit.definitions.json /tmp/rabbit.definitions.json`
3. Add an environment variable when starting the container, for example, using docker-compose.yml:

   ```yaml
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_SERVER_ADDITIONAL_ERL_ARGS=-rabbitmq_management load_definitions "/tmp/rabbit.definitions.json"
   ```

Comment: Easy peasy! I opted to paste the contents of my .json into a Docker secret.

Comment: This is the way!

Answer (score 4):

There is a simple way to upload definitions to Docker container. 
Use preconfigured node to export the definitions to `json` file.

Then move this file to the same folder where you have the Dockerfile and create a `rabbitmq.config` in the same folder too. Here is the context of `rabbitmq.config`:

```
[
    { rabbit, [
        { loopback_users, [ ] },
        { tcp_listeners, [ 5672 ] },
        { ssl_listeners, [ ] },
        { hipe_compile, false }
    ] },
    { rabbitmq_management, [ { listener, [
        { port, 15672 },
        { ssl, false }
    ] },
        { load_definitions, "/etc/rabbitmq/definitions.json" }
    ] }
].
```

Then prepare an appropriate Dockerfile:

```
FROM rabbitmq:3.6.14-management-alpine
ADD definitions.json /etc/rabbitmq
ADD rabbitmq.config /etc/rabbitmq

EXPOSE 4369 5672 25672 15672
```

The definitions will be loaded during image build. When you run the container all definitions will be already applied.

Answer (score 0):

You could start your container with RabbitMQ, configure the resources (queues, exchanges, bindings) and then commit your configured container as a new image. This image can be used to start new containers.

More details at https://docs.docker.com/articles/basics/#committing-saving-a-container-state

Comment: Actually thinking more deeply about your question, why would you need it if resource declaration using RabbitMQ API is idempotent, so you can call `queueDeclare` or `exchangeDeclare` without worrying if the resource already exists. I always recreate my container when I want to reset the configuration and just run my application, and it configures all that is needed inside RabbitMQ.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this is an option, but the absolute easiest way to handle this situation is to periodically create a new, empty RabbitMQ container and have it join the first container as part of the RabbitMQ cluster.  The configuration of the queues will be copied to the second container.

Then, you can stop the container and create a versioned image in your docker repository of the new container using [docker commit](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerimages/#updating-and-committing-an-image).  This process will only save the changes that you have made to your image, and then it would enable you to not have to worry about re-importing the configuration each time.  You would just have to get the latest image to have the latest configuration!

Answer (score 0):

> Modern releases support definition import directly in the core, without the need to preconfigure the management plugin.

```
# New in RabbitMQ 3.8.2.
# Does not require management plugin to be enabled.
load_definitions = /path/to/definitions/file.json
```

From [Schema Definition Export and Import RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/definitions.html#import-on-boot) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [official rabbitmq image](https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq) you can mount definition file in `/etc/rabbitmq` shown as below, rabbitmq will load this definitions on when daemon started

```
docker run -v ./your_local_definitions_file.json:/etc/rabbitmq/definitions.json ......
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it in the following way:

1. I imported the definition using management UI and I called the file `definitions.json`
   [image]
2. I created a `rabbitmq.conf` file with following data: 
    `load_definitions = /etc/rabbitmq/definitions.json` 
   [Config File Formats](https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html#config-file-formats)
3. Next, I created simple dockerfile

```
    FROM rabbitmq:management-alpine
    COPY definitions.json /etc/rabbitmq/definitions.json
    COPY rabbitmq.conf /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf
```

4. Build the image: `docker build -t your-image-name .`
5. Run the container: `docker run -d --name your-container-name -p 15672:15672 -p 5672:5672 your-image-name`

Remember to place all files in one folder.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed @autonomy commentary to @andrey answer about Docker' secrets and end up with the following yml file:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  rabbit:
    image: rabbitmq:3.6.1-management
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_SERVER_ADDITIONAL_ERL_ARGS=-rabbitmq_management load_definitions "/run/secrets/rabbit_config"
    secrets:
      - rabbit_config

secrets:
  rabbit_config:
    file: ./rabbit_definitions.json
```